# Spring data jpa failed to pass named parameters in native subquery for db2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2

Unable to pass named parameters in `@NamedNativeQuery` in spring data jpa

my repo:

```
   @Query(value = "select stat.desc as desc," + 
    " stat.priority as priority," + 
    " (case when sum(activeUser) is null then 0 else sum(activeUser) end) as activeUser," + 
    " (case when sum(totalUser) is null then 0 else sum(totalUser) end) as totalUser" + 
    " from lookup.user stat left outer join" + 
    " (" + 
    " select user.role as role, " + 
    " sum (case when user.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as activeUser," + 
    " count(*) as totalUser," + 
    " user.group as group" + 
    " from Ctrl.user user" + 
    " where user.group =:userGroup " + 
    " and user.branch_code =:branchCode " + 
    " group by user.role,user.group" + 
    " ) as tbl on stat.role = tbl.role and stat.group = tbl.group" + 
    " where stat.group =:userGroup " + 
    " group by stat.desc, stat.priority" + 
    "", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<com.cimb.dto.UserStatusSummary> getSummaryReport(@Param(value = "userGroup") String userGroup, @Param(value = "branchCode") String branchCode);
```

The underlying database is `DB2`

When I tried to access that method I am hitting following error.

```
   DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.25.13
```

if I hard code those named parameters with values then it's working.

I can not use `jpql` as real queries have some subqueries in it, so I cant use `JPQL`

**Edit Update**

After some digging, I have found out that, the parameters I am passing are in the subquery, since `JPA` don't have subquery concept it's not injecting into named parameters which resulting in a syntax error.

Now how to work with Subqueries in `JPA`

Please help.

Comment: What are the values? And how does the version with literals look like? What is the datatype of the `branch_code` and `group` columns?

Comment: @JensSchauder Values are just plain strings like `1233wfee`, 'TBM' data type is `varchar` for both of them

Comment: Why anyone wants to close this Question information is not enough to reproduce this problem ? then please let me know.

Comment: @JensSchauder Hi, I have found the reason why it's not working, if you see my query I have one subquery in it  and I am passing two params into that subquery, since `jpa` dont have subquery concept it failed to inject those params into subquery resulting in `DB2 Error Code -302` , now I dont know how to pass params to sub queries.

Comment: I doubt that. JPQL doesn't have subqueries, but that would resut in a different error. Also you have native query here, so SQL / JDBC is relevant and that would be an "interesting" bug.

Comment: HI, I am facing similar problem. Please let us know if you have resolved this issue and how.

Comment: @MayurBeldar I gave up, and started using Native Queries, if you have enough time could you please post a testable code to this ticket Which I have raised https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1570