# Spring specification with subquery, union, join and case statements

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have very long and complex queries, I am using spring data,

can someone please help me to achieve below query in spring jpa, I can't use native query as spring is not supporting parameter injection in subqueries.

```
select desc as desc, priority as priority, activeUser as activeUser, 
totalUser as totalUser
 from  
(
  select stat.desc as desc, 
  stat.priority as priority,
  (case when sum(activeUser) is null then 0 else sum(activeUser) end) as 
  activeUser, 
   (case when sum(totalUser) is null then 0 else sum(totalUser) end) as 
  totalUser
  from lookup.user stat left outer join 
  (
  select user.role as role,  
  sum (case when user.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as activeUser,
  count(*) as totalUser,
  user.group as group
  from ctrl.user user  
  where user.group =:userGroup 
  and user.branch_code =:branchCode
  group by user.role,user.group
  ) as tbl on stat.role = tbl.role and stat.group = tbl.group
  where stat.group =:userGroup
  group by stat.desc, stat.priority
 union
 select 'Total' as desc, 
 '999' as priority,
   (case when sum(activeUser) is null then 0 else sum(activeUser) end) as 
    activeUser, 
   (case wh en sum(totalUser) is null then 0 else sum(totalUser) end) as 
   totalUser
  from lookup.user stat left outer join 
   (
  select user.role as role,  
  sum (case when user.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' then 1 else 0 end) as activeUser,
    count(*) as totalUser,
   user.group as group
   from ctrl.user user 
   where user.group =:userGroup
   and user.branch_code =:branchCode
   group by user.role,user.group
   ) as tbl on stat.role = tbl.role and stat.group = tbl.group
   where stat.group =:userGroup
    ) as tblMain order by priority
```

I have tried to generate `predicate` as below but its not taking `selects`

```
  Specification<CtrlUser> sp= new Specification<CtrlUser>() {

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<CtrlUser> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            query.multiselect(root.get("role"), cb.selectCase().when(root.get("status").in("ACTIVE"), 1).otherwise(0).alias("ActiveUsers"),
                    cb.count(root).alias("totalUsers"),root.get("group")).groupBy(root.get("role"),root.get("group"));
            return cb.and(cb.equal(root.get("branchCode"), branchCode), cb.equal(root.get("group"), userGroup));
        }
    };
```

I have searched online, but not much of luck.

if require more info, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by " spring is not supporting parameter injection in subqueries"?

Comment: if you see, my subquery has injectable parameters, when I have used `@NativeQuery` spring is not injecting, parameters to that subquery which leads to `SQL Grammar Expression` i mean its traget generated query become `branch_code=:branchCode` instead of `branch_code='xxxx'`, but if I hard code values like `branch_code = 'xxx' ` then its working.

Comment: I have raised a Question on this  [Failed to inject in subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660203/spring-data-jpa-failed-to-pass-named-parameters-in-native-subquery-for-db2)

Comment: @JensSchauder did raise a ticket please help to look into it. [Jira Ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1570)